# Can not access mysql in centos 7 after installation

Tags: mysql, linux, centos7, lamp, mysql-error-1064

I downloaded mysql community repo, and installed mysql server using.
yum install mysql
yum install mysql-server

And started service using systemctl start mysqld
systemctl status mysqld command states that server is running,

but can not login to mysql using mysql -u root,
it says "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Answer (score 0):

If thats doesn't worked for you , try the same but provide -p
you can try like this :

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and provide your password for root to enter into the mysql console.